# TypeError: button_click() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, arguments, typeerror

I always keep on getting a type error saying that I am missing 1 required positional argument which is the 'self' how can I fix this?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from client import*

root = tkinter.Tk()
class view():    
    root.geometry("250x300")
    F1 =Frame()
    L = Listbox(F1)
    L.grid(row=0, column =0) 

    L.pack()

    F = open("users.txt","r")
    M = F.read()
    cont = M.split()

    for each in cont:
        ind = each.find("#") + 1
        L.insert(ind+1 ,each[ind:])
        break

    F.close()

    F1.pack()

    # strng_ind = -1
def button_click(self):
        self.form.destroy()
        Chatclient().design()

button = Button(root, text="Create Group Chat", command= button_click)

button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is the `button_click` supposed to be indented into the class?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
button = Button(root, text="Create Group Chat", command= button_click)
```

Note the command - it says to invoke `button_click`, and will with no arguments. You defined the click function as

```
def button_click(self):
```

so when you click the button and invoke `button_click` **with no arguments**, since your definition requires a self argument - whether if it's because it's in a class or for whatever reason - you get the error. Either get rid of `self` in the arguments

```
def button_click():
```

or if it's supposed to be a part of the class definition, only define the Button with a valid object. For example, you can put inside `def __init__(self)`:

```
self.button = Button(root, text="Create Group Chat", command= self.button_click)
```

with the added bonus of constructing your GUI in the constructor, which is good design.

Comment: Dropping the `(self)` worked. Strangely, I need to have it as an argument when I trigger the function by pressing `Enter`, coded with `my_tk_entry_widget.bind('<Key-Return>',                             my_function)`. I made this a new Q/A at [Either Enter or button trigger "TypeError ... missing 1 required positional argument" or "TypeError ... takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76276568/either-enter-or-button-trigger-typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argu/76276569#76276569).

Answer (score 2):

put `button_click` method inside the class `view`, [some explication about self](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/)

```
class view():

    ...

    def button_click(self):
        self.form.destroy()
        Chatclient().design()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the function definition for button_click() inside the class.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from client import*

root = tkinter.Tk()
class view():    
    root.geometry("250x300")
    F1 =Frame()
    L = Listbox(F1)
    L.grid(row=0, column =0) 

    L.pack()

    F = open("users.txt","r")
    M = F.read()
    cont = M.split()

    for each in cont:
        ind = each.find("#") + 1
        L.insert(ind+1 ,each[ind:])
        break

    F.close()

    F1.pack()

    # strng_ind = -1
    def button_click(self):
        self.form.destroy()
        Chatclient().design()

button = Button(root, text="Create Group Chat", command= button_click)

button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Basically, you need to indent the code for the function definition.

Actually, when you place the code for function inside the class then it becomes a member function for that class and by passing the argument self, you just actually use a reference to the object(instance of the class) for which that function is called. It's like `this` in C++ if you know about that.

You can read more about self [here](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/).

Answer (score 0):

You also need to indent the last two `button` lines. I checked your code by commenting out anything that I could not test:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
# from client import *

root = tkinter.Tk()
class view():    
    root.geometry("250x300")
    F1 =Frame()
    L = Listbox(F1)
    L.grid(row=0, column =0) 

    L.pack()

    # F = open("users.txt","r")
    # M = F.read()
    # cont = M.split()

    # for each in cont:
    #     ind = each.find("#") + 1
    #     L.insert(ind+1 ,each[ind:])
    #     break

    # F.close()

    F1.pack()

    # strng_ind = -1
    def button_click():
        # self.form.destroy()
        print('test')
        # Chatclient().design()

    button = Button(root, text="Create Group Chat", command=button_click)
    button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Out:

[image]